# Fire Javascript alert when counter reaches 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have a page that updates whenever another entry is added to the database. It displays the timestamp, and then starts counting up using jQuery, along with moment.js to help with time formatting. This is the code for that:

```
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date('".$array['dateAdded']."');
        $('#since".$array['id']."').countdown({since: austDay, significant: 1, layout:  '{d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl}{s>}'});
});
```

I need to be able to fire an alert whenever a given entry is 10 minutes past the timestamp date and time. I assume the script would need to continually check to see if that's the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which `.countdown()` plugin is it? I expect it would have an option to set a callback that will be called when the counter gets to zero (or to the finish time).

Comment: I know it uses the "countdown" language, but it actually counts up to infinity. I edited it to count the other direction, so there is no finish time. I just need to be able to detect when the counter hits 10 minutes past the time on the timestamp.

Comment: To answer your first question though, this is the plugin: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: Well that plugin does let you specify an `onTick` callback, though in the function you provide you'd have to check if the 10 minutes has passed yet and you'd be doing that check every second. Or you could do it independently with `setTimeout(function(){alert("10 minutes!");}, 10*60*1000)`...

Comment: If I use setTimeout, it doesn't take the entry timestamp into consideration, and will just fire every 10 minutes for every element, rather than 10 minutes from the point of the timestamp. Is there a way I can pull in a timestamp and calculate 10 minutes out using JS or PHP?

Comment: Since you are using moment.js you can easily parse the timestamp and add ten minutes to it:: `var finish = moment("yourTimestampHere","yourTimestampFormatHere").add('m',10)`. If you wanted to find out how far away that is use the `.diff()` method: `var millisecs = finish.diff(moment())` (or similar: I'm not exactly sure of the usage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with for this problem, using a mix of Javascript and PHP.

```
$now = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$plusTen = date("Y-m-d, h:i:s", strtotime("+10 minutes", strtotime($array['dateAdded'])));
$difference = strtotime($plusTen) - strtotime($now);
$difference = round($difference,2) * 1000;

if($difference > 0){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){staleAlert();}, '.$difference.')
</script>';
}
```